# hook_help() argument

Tags: 7, hooks

I don't see the second parameter `$arg` being use in the function.

```
function hook_help($path, $arg) {
  // ....
}
```

Why should I declare it? What is its use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--help--help.api.php/function/hook_help/7). It states:

> $arg An array that corresponds to the
>   return value of the arg() function,
>   for modules that want to provide help
>   that is specific to certain values of
>   wildcards in $path. For example, you
>   could provide help for the path
>   'user/1' by looking for the path
>   'user/%' and $arg[1](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--help--help.api.php/function/hook_help/7) == '1'. This
>   given array should always be used
>   rather than directly invoking arg(),
>   because your hook implementation may
>   be called for other purposes besides
>   building the current page's help. Note
>   that depending on which module is
>   invoking hook_help, $arg may contain
>   only empty strings. Regardless,
>   $arg[0] to $arg[11] will always be
>   set.

Example:

```
function hook_help($path, $arg) {
    if($path == 'user/%'){
        if($arg[1] < 10) {
            return 'one of the early users';
        }
        else {
            return 'foo';
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this without the `$args` would be ugly.

Comment: i have read the api, but still can't understand it well.

Comment: $arg contains the arguments of the current page, that's it. Also, note that while it is great that you accept answers to your questions, you might want to wait a few hours or maybe a 1-2 days, especially if the answer isn't 100% clear to you. This question is now marked as answered, so many people won't even look at it anymore and you won't get any other answers.

Comment: The thing is, i edited my answer after his comment (the example). I think now it's clear to him.

Answer (score 1):

> Why should I declare it? What is its use?

@nonsenz already answered about the use of that argument. I will reply to the first question.

You should declared it if you need it. Hook implementations don't need to declare the same arguments declared in the hook definition.

I could define the function using the following code, and it would work the same.

```
function mymodule_help($secret_key) {
}
```

Using the same parameter names you see in the hook definition helps who reads your code, and avoids to document the parameters used by the function, as they match the parameters described in the hook definition.
Parameters that are not necessary can be omitted. I normally add them, in the case I rewrite the hook code, and I need them; if I write the parameters I find in the hook documentation, I don't need to change them later.